# Is there a Microsoft Graph API call to get deltas/changes of lists?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-list

I would like to be able to pull for changes, or be notified of changes, in a Sharepoint list, which is not associated with a drive. This is a list of pure metadata stored in the columns/fields, so a change would be any new items, or changes to the field values of existing items in the list.

I am aware of the Graph API `/delta` route, but this appears only available on drives.

By the looks of it, I have to use the Sharepoint API directly (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/synchronize-sharepoint-items-using-the-rest-service). Is that right, or is there a way with Graph API?

Comment: Yes, there is no support yet for sharepoint delta queries according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources). You can raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the Product team may develop it in the future.

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no support yet for sharepoint delta queries according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview#supported-resources). You can raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the Product team may develop it in the future.